# How do I interconvert Calc's HMS forms and seconds?

Tags: time-date, calc, parse-time, date-to-time

Is there a built-in way to convert/toggle between [GNU Emacs Calc's HMS forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/HMS-Forms.html) and seconds?  I'd also like to easily be able to add numbers as seconds and/or minutes to an existing HMS form.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "*HMS form*". Do you mean a list of numbers? A formatted time string? The question is unclear so far, and so risks being closed.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by your question, see the Elisp manual, node [Time Parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html) or other time-related nodes under node [System Interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Interface.html).

Answer (score 5):

One way of going from an HMS form to the number of seconds is hinted by a line from the [HMS forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/HMS-Forms.html) page:

> Dividing two HMS forms produces a real-valued ratio of the two angles.

So if an HMS form is on the stack

```
5@ 30' 0"
```

entering one second to the stack

```
1"
```

and dividing by it

```
/
```

gives the number of seconds:

```
19800.
```

Not exactly a convert but it's only three keystrokes.